# PHP multiple arrays into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have clinicDays array which contains the checkboxes values from Monday to Sunday and the clinic id values:

```
clinicDays[]:4|1
clinicDays[]:1|1
```

where the first number before the pipe is the id of the clinic and the last number which is the right side of the pipe is the number of the day, what I am trying to do is if the clinicDays has value then, put the values into the table and delete the old values if they are not matching with the new ones and if the clinicDays array is empty then delete all rows associated to the `$doctorid` and `clinic_id`

INSERTing the values part is working all fine, however I couldn't get the DELETE parts working, can some guide me through?

For this I have 4 tables:
1-dg_clinics (id, clinic_name)
2-dg_doctors (id, doctor_name)
3-dg_days (id, day_name)
4-dg_clinic_days (id, clinic_id, doctor_id, day_id)

```
$doctorid = $_POST['doctor_doctorid'];

if(isset($_POST['clinicDays']))
{
    $clinics = array();
    foreach($_POST['clinicDays'] as $clinic_day_values){

        $clinic_day_values = explode("|", $clinicday);

        $q5 = "SELECT * FROM dg_doctors_clinic_days WHERE doctor_id = {$doctorid} AND clinic_id = {$clinic_day_values[0]} AND day_id = {$clinic_day_values[1]}";
        $getClinicDay = $db->query($q5);
        $num_days = mysql_num_rows($getClinicDay);

        if( $num_days == 0 ) {
            $q6 = "INSERT INTO dg_doctors_clinic_days (clinic_id,doctor_id,day_id,value,date_added) VALUES ({$clinic_day_values[0]},{$doctorid},$clinic_day_values[1],1,NOW())";
            $r6 = $db->query($q6);
        }
    }
    $items = implode(",", $_POST['checkAllClinics']);
    $q3 = "DELETE FROM dg_clinic_doctors WHERE doctor_id = {$doctorid} AND clinic_id = {} AND day_id NOT IN ({$items})";
    $r3 = $db->query($q3);

} else {
    $q8 = "DELETE FROM dg_doctors_clinic_days WHERE doctor_id = {$doctorid}";
    $r8 = $db->query($q8);
}
```

Comment: I've just added the question @cale_b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could simplify your code AND solve the problem by moving the delete to to beginning, which will ALWAYS execute (and before the inserts), that way you don't have to keep track of the records that need to be deleted, and you don't have to check if the record already exists.

Based on the code you've posted, you're always deleting ALL days unless they are posted anyway, so try this simplified code:

```
$doctorid = $_POST['doctor_doctorid'];

// Delete the clinic days for the doctor.
$q8 = "DELETE FROM dg_doctors_clinic_days WHERE doctor_id = {$doctorid}";
$r8 = $db->query($q8);
// IF any clinic days are posted, save them....
if (isset($_POST['clinicDays'])) {
    foreach($_POST['clinicDays'] as $clinic_day_values) {
        // NOTE: The variable $clinicday is NOT being set, is this a typo in your original code?
        $clinic_day_values = explode("|", $clinicday);
        $q6 = "INSERT INTO dg_doctors_clinic_days (clinic_id,doctor_id,day_id,value,date_added) VALUES ({$clinic_day_values[0]},{$doctorid},$clinic_day_values[1],1,NOW())";
        $r6 = $db->query($q6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you fro your help however, in your code you are deleting all the records for that doctor, what I need to do is delete all records for that doctor for that specific clinic. for example: doctor A can work on clinic 1 on Mondays and Tuesdays, but not work on clinic 2  @cale_b